# windows 8 taking long time to open Mac server share

Tags: windows, network-share, mac-osx-server, connection, tcp-slow-start

I have a machine running windows 8 on a Mac server environment. When mounting or accessing a small/empty shared folder on the network the computer connects fine. When accessing another shared folder on the network it doesn't seem to load (I left this running and it had connected by the next morning)(there are multiple files and folders and many sub directories). Connecting to this folder via ftp or as a webserver the content is accessible straight away.

I have tried the following without result so far:
- removing windows from managing the home group
- removed the computer off the home group
- different/slower speed and duplex modes
- various suggestions making sure services are running and sharing settings correctly setup
- folder contents set to general (for rendering thumbnails etc)
- flush DNS
- cleared login accounts associated with the IP

The computer does have the following setup:
- static IP
- correct work group name

If more info is required I will post.

Suggestions will be appreciated.
Regards,
Nick

Comment: Fire up tcpdump/wireshark.  See if you can see what is getting dropped, or where the delays are happening.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I will only be able to revert once all the users have left the building (±8 hours away) as the computer is currently sharing a drive (which makes the situation more sensitive). I will let you know more when I know more.

Comment: I ran wireshark and unfortunately my knowledge on the inner workings of TCP is limited. I did however see that the connection was being established and that after a while there was data being sent to keep the connection open (single bits) but no other additional information stood out, it didn't seem that any other data was being transmitted.

Comment: Some additional information is that I can ping and trace route without any issues or delays. I have tried some further suggestions such as forcing smb1, disabling autotuning, disabling flow control disabling tcp4/6 offset, updating drivers all to no avail.

Comment: I have this log from the server if it helps:

Oct 29 19:15:54 Servers-Mac-mini.local digest-service[76185]: digest-request: user=SERVERS-MAC-MIN\\server
Oct 29 19:15:54 Servers-Mac-mini.local digest-service[76185]: digest-request kdc: ok user=SERVERS-MAC-MIN\\server proto=ntlmv2 flags: NEG_KEYEX, ENC_128, NEG_VERSION, NEG_TARGET_INFO, NEG_NTLM2, NEG_ALWAYS_SIGN, NEG_NTLM, NEG_SIGN, NEG_TARGET, NEG_UNICODE
Oct 29 19:17:45 Servers-Mac-mini.local collabd[76239]: [CSNotificationService.m:96 10304000 +262ms] XXX: Woke up, but didn't receive anything. This shouldn't happen, possible bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry for all the comments, I have a working solution, this would not satisfy someone who has spent the money purchasing Server from the App Store.

I installed **smbup (http://eduo.info/apps/smbup)** which basically sets up and manages samba to replace the smb that Apple has with the original samba project. A manual installation of samba may have also resolved the issue. Just to clarify this is on the Mac running as the server.

I can however say through out the whole ordeal that I have learnt a LOT more about mac and windows sharing (but doubt I have scraped too far under the surface).

@Zoredache, thanks for the suggestion!